# Prove that it is a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, permutations

Let $S$ is a set of all subgroups of group $G$ and for each element $a\in G$ we match a function $c_a: S \rightarrow S$:
$$c_a(H) = aHa^{-1}$$
How to prove that we set an action from $G$ onto $S$.

I know that i have to prove that $c_a\in Perm(S)$ and $a\mapsto c_a$ is a homomorphism, but i don't how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to prove that $G$ acts on the given set is to prove that $c_e(H) = H$ for all $H\le G$, but this is trivially true and $c_{ab}(H) = c_a(c_b(H))$ for all $H \le G$. Using the definition of $c_a$ we have that:

$$c_{ab}(H) = (ab)H(ab)^{-1} = (ab)H(b^{-1}a^{-1})$$
$$c_a(c_b(H)) = c_a(bHb^{-1}) = (ab)H(b^{-1}a^{-1})$$

Therefore we can conclude that $G$ acts on the set of subgroups of $G$.

---

On the other side using your method all we need to prove is that $c_a$ is a bijection and $\lambda: G \to$ Sym$(X)$, given by $a \to c_a$ is a group homomorphism.

First of all let $H=K$. Then we have that $c_a(H) = aHa^{-1} = aKa^{-1} = c_a(K)$ therefore $c_a$ is well-defined. Now let $c_a(H) = c_a(K) \implies aHa^{-1} = aKa^{-1} \implies H=K$, therefore $c_a$ is injection. Now let $H \le G$, as $a^{-1} \in G$ we have that: $c_a(a^{-1}Ha) = (aa^{-1})H(aa^{-1}) = H$. Therefore $c_a$ is surjection and eventually a bijection.

Now for the second part all we need to prove is:

$$\lambda(ab) = \lambda(a)\lambda(b) \iff c_{ab} = c_{a}c_{b}$$

But we have already established this as true in the first part.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Could you also please recommend a book for a group theory. I already heard about Lang's Undergraduate Algebra, but are there any other decent books about group theory?

Comment: @Intainer Well I don't know whether this is good or not, but I will tell you which books I learned from. First I used Gilbert's "Elements of Modern Algebra" and Herstein's "Abstract Algebra" in my first Abstract Algebra undergraduate course. They are quite easy to follow and you don't need much preknowledge. After that I read Fraleigh "A First Course in Abstract Algebra". It's a little bit more advanced than the first two, as it also enters deeper in ring theory and it introduces Galois theory, but it's quite easy to follow.

Comment: @Intainer Also I really liked some of the excercises in the Fraleigh's book. After that I started reading Rotman's "Theory of Groups" and Hall's "The Theory of Groups". I had troubles with the Rotman's book and I needed to spend more time reading it. On the other hand Hall's book is much more concise and easier to understand. Anyway the excercises in the books are very good and will help you with understanding group theory much better.

Comment: @Intainer Another book that I really like is Martin Isaacs' "Finite Groups". It's the most advanced of all the books I've mentioned, but I like his language, as it was understandable and I had no problems following the proofs. I especially liked the exercises included in the book, which are great and range in difficulty.

Comment: Yea, abstract algebra without exercises and examples is quite overwhelming.

Comment: @Intainer You're right. When you're solving problem it's like proving some theorems, which are actually properties. I especially like solving excercises that are general, not for a particular group. Also it make you more familiar to the topic.

Comment: It was nice for me to get some advices from such a pro in group theory as you are. Thank you again.

Comment: @Intainer I'm flattered, but I wouldn't really call myself a pro. Group theory is a topic of my interest, but I don't really think I'm that good in that area of math.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a group action of $G$ on $S$ is as follows: $1 \cdot s = s$ for all $s \in S$, and for all $a,b \in G$ and $s \in S$ we have $a \cdot (b \cdot s) = (ab) \cdot s$. Proceeding, we see $1 \cdot H = 1 H 1^{-1} = H$, so the identity property of group actions is satisfied. Now let $a,b \in G$. Then $a \cdot (b \cdot H) = a \cdot (b H b^{-1}) = a(b H b^{-1})a^{-1} = ab H b^{-1}a^{-1} = ab H (ab)^{-1} = (ab) \cdot H$.